# I need to have a UiLabel displaying two integers "minutes:seconds" without shifting left and right as the numbers change

Tags: swift

I have created a countdown timer "Minutes:Seconds"  the logic works but I have a display issue. As the numbers change the uilabel text shifts ever so slightly left and right and it is ugly. Any ideas?

This is how I change the label currently

```
let strMinutes = String(format:" %02d",minutes)
let strseconds = String(format:"%02d",displayseconds)

displayTimeLabel.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strseconds) "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent your digits from shifting, use a font with mono-spaced digits such as *Courier New Bold*, *Helvetica Neue*, *Verdana*, *American Typewriter*, *Chalkboard SE*, *Copperplate*, *Gill Sans*, *Marker Felt*, or *Trebuchet MS*.

You set this in the *Attributes Inspector* for the label:

[image]

I would suggest setting the **Alignment** to center your text as well.

---

You can do your code in one line:

```
displayTimeLabel.text = String(format: " %02d:%02d ", minutes, displayseconds)
```

Comment: The Helvetica Neue worked thanks.  I was trying a digital font

Answer (score 0):

I think an option would be choose a Mono spaced font. To do this, you can select your label and open the "Utilities" panel. Then show the "Attributes inspector" and finally in "Font". There, you can select "Fonte: Custom" and choose a monospaced font like Courier New Bold and Helvetica Neue

Answer (score 0):

Change your text alignment to center, and set the width of your label to have enough padding on both sides so that its width doesn't change when the content changes. That way you can use any font, doesn't have to be monospaced.