# Getting ... in Label Output Instead of My Function Output in Swift Timer

Tags: swift, timer, uilabel

I have written some code to make a countdown timer that works in minutes and seconds using the following code to make the label (called time label) display in the format mm:ss

```
var timevalue = 30
var seconds = 30
var minutes = 0
var timer = Timer()

func timerdisplay() {
    if (minutes<10 && seconds<10){
        timelabel.text! = "0" + String(minutes) + ":0" + String(seconds)
    }
    else if (minutes<10){
        timelabel.text! = "0" + String(minutes) + ":" + String(seconds)
    }
    else if (minutes>=10 && seconds<10){
        timelabel.text! = String(minutes) + ":0" + String(seconds)
    }
    else {
        timelabel.text! = String(minutes) + ":" + String(seconds)
    }

}
```

It does this for a large percentage of the numbers, with the timer functioning well through the 00 (ss) stage and the minutes counting down appropriately. In short the timer is working.

However, some numbers in the seconds part appear as ...

I have attempted to add in some fixes, like moving all of the code into a function to call it each time it's needed, making sure that I define the datatype for all the variables involved and adding ! to my text labels to verify that they are not null - all with no success.

More confusingly it's the same numbers every time and they aren't related (ie in the 9th minute maybe 15 seconds doesn't display, in the 4th minute 4 seconds doesn't display, in the 3rd all of the 50s don't display).

I'm really at a loss.

Help appreciated. If anyone needs more of the code to see if something went wrong somewhere else, happy to provide it in full.

Comment: Your label isn't big enough. Make it wider so it can fit all possible text you put in it. Or setup the label to automatically use a smaller font to allow the text to fit.

Comment: You might also want to use a fixed width font so the numbers don't shift around.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35351343/1630618

Comment: Embarassingly simple fix. Much appreciated, glad the code was OK.